# Java - Turning the for-loop counter back based on a conditional

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

The following is part of the code for my college assignment.

```
else if (!codeList.contains(userCode)) {
                    i--; // i is the counter for the for-loop
                }
else if (userQuantity[i]==0) {
                    i--;
                }
```

The first part makes sure that if the user enters the wrong code, the counter i does not increment 1, or rather, it subtracts 1 from the recently incremented counter. This part works fine.

The second part however is what I seem to be having problems with. userQuantity[] is an int array and it has to be an array. This does not seem to do anything to the code. Even if 0 is entered for the quantity, it still incrememnts the counter which is not desireable.

**I should explain, to avoid confusion, that this is an infinite for-loop (with a break statement). The reason I am doing a for-loop is because I am required to. Is it because of my for-loop that the condition isn't working or am I doing something completely wrong with it?**

This is for my college assignment so I would appreciate answers with explanation and not just quick-fixes. If you need me to explain, let me know please.

Comment: I have edited the question further to avoid any focus on the wrong part of the code. Thanks for the help so far :-) I have noted all the comments for future practice, but for now I am required to follow the instructions for my assignment. Another thing to note is that this is a very basic Java course and I am a noob.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although it's not strictly illegal in Java, it's not a good idea to change the value of the for loop control variable from within the loop. (Such modification *is* illegal in some other languages.)

By changing the loop iteration variable within the loop, you're messing with the implicit assumptions offered by your use of a `for` loop. For example, if a reader sees:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

the reader will rightfully assume that the loop is intended to execute exactly 10 times (or, no more than 10 if there is a `break` in there). However, if you go changing the value of `i` within the loop, this assumption is no longer valid.

If you *must* change the value of the counter, I would suggest writing this as a `while` loop instead:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    // ...
    i++;
}
```

along with a comment that explains why you are changing `i` within the loop and what it means to do so.

Comment: Thanks, your answer seems to have helped a lot. I would like to ask though, is messing with the counter within the loop only "bad" because of what you wrote above or are there more reasons?

Comment: I would say that's the primary reason. In Java, there aren't any *technical* reasons why you can't change a `for` loop control variable within the loop. That is, the compiler lets you do it and you can reason about the resulting code within the rules of Java. However, since code is *read* many more times than it is *written*, it's always a good idea not to surprise the reader with unexpected behaviours in code. For example, it's perfectly legal but not necessarily a good idea for a function to change the value of a global variable without clearly indicating that it is doing so.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. There are a lot of practices, it seems, that my university teaches that are not good. In fact, in the textbook, it says "a while loop is something you will never have to use" (paraphrased). Now that seems to be a lie right here.

Comment: Yeah, that's rubbish. I would say, however, that I use `while { }` loops far more frequently than `do { } while` loops. So there's definitely a scale of usefulness there.

Comment: @nickecarlo - what textbook is that?  I want to add it to my list of textbooks that should NOT be recommended to students.

Comment: @StephenC It is a textbook printed by UOL for its students. AS for whether I am misunderstanding the text, I don't think so. It is fairly clearly spelled out. The university is probably just that screwed up. I am stuck here for now so I have to deal with whatever comes my way.

Comment: @GregHewgill This assignment is the first time I have used the do {} while loop. Other than that, the university sort of keeps us using the simple for-loop.

Answer (score 4):

This is very bad practice. Change the for loop to a while loop and only increment if

```
 codeList.contains(userCode)==true or userQuantity[i]!=0.
```

Answer (score 1):

> I should explain, to avoid confusion, that this is an infinite for-loop (with a break statement). The reason I am doing a for-loop is because I am required to. Is it because of my for-loop that the condition isn't working or am I doing something completely wrong with it?

I have a feeling that you are misunderstanding the requirements (e.g. you are not *required* to use a `for` loop), or that there is a mistake in your thinking; i.e. there is a simpler solution that doesn't involve the counter going backwards.

(It is surprising that a programming exercise would require you to write code that most experienced Java programmers would agree is bad code.  The simple explanation is that it is not.)

Either way:

- Changing the loop variable in a `for` loop is bad practice, for the reasons described by Greg.
- The idea of an "infinite for loop" is really strange.  The following is legal Java ...

  ```
  for (int i = 0; true; i++) {
      ...
  }
  ```

  but the idiomatic way to write it is:

  ```
  int i = 0;
  while (true) {
      ...
      i++; // ... at the appropriate point / points
  }
  ```

  ... which in most cases means that you don't need to make the variable go backwards at all.

Comment: I can put the whole thing using a while loop in delimeters to see if they are okay with it for next time.