# incrementing the counter of a for-loop

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop

I came by an exercise in a [Hakerrank challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sock-merchant) where I used a basic for loop to iterate over an array, then I thought about incrementing the loop counter based on a condition. Here is my solution :

```
public static int sockMerchant(int n, int[] ar) {
    int pairs = 0;
    Arrays.sort(ar);
    if (n % 2 != 0) n = n - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if (ar[i] == ar[i + 1]) {
            ++pairs;
            // incrementing the loop counter
            i++;
        }
    }
    return pairs;
}
```

I'm wondering if there is any incidence or issues when incrementing the for-loop counter. Any ideas guys of things to be careful about with the written code?

Comment: Some people downvote faster than their own shadow ;-) You algo (n--) would miss, for instance, `[ 1, 2, 2 ]`... Besides, there is no much gain by reducing the number of loops by 1, here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all programming languages allow the modification of a loop's index.   If that is the case, then use whatever method that is appropriate or idiomatic for that language.

But, Java allows the modification of a loop's index.

Take a look at the detailed answer by [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9012318/13651978